# How to connect to my server via a html form

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery-mobile

I have set up a simple log in page on a mobile app to take in user name and password. I have also set up a server and it displays {"loggedIn":true} if I insert the correct password and username on the url. I want the same think to happen but this time I want to insert the password/ username info on the mobile app.

This is the url of the server: http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/?id=param&password=param

The param in the url will be replaced by the inputs from the html form. I am not sure as to how I am going to be able to make this link between the mobile app and the server. I understand this method of connecting is not secure and will try to use hashtag later on. I am just trying to establish the connection for now. Please advice how I can do this connection.

My html codes as follows:

```
<div data-role="page" id="loginPage" data-theme="e"><!--Start of Log In Page-->
            <header data-role="header">
                <h1>Log In</h1>       
            </header>

            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
              <p>
                <label for="username">UserName</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
              </p>
            </form>

            <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
              <label for="password">Password   </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
            </form>
            <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Log In" />

            <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h1></h1>
            </footer>
        </div><!--End of Log In Page-->
```

Comment: You need to create **one** <form> in such a way that, when submitted, it will make a request like the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following;

```
 <form id="form2" name="form2" method="GET" action="http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/">
        <label for="password">Username   </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />

        <label for="password">Password   </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login"/>    
    </form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").on("click", function() {
            $.get( "http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/", $("#form2").serialize(), function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: When I click nothing happens. As you mentioned it makes a request to above url. If password/id is correct, how am I going to know if it is connected. Would an alert() work if I place it under the form for me to check if I am connected? Tnks.

Comment: Have you got jQuery included in your project?

Comment: @keshk you can do that with ajax, see my updated answer. Be careful on, I have also updated html form. Use whole code

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one form with both fields inside, with method set to "GET" and action should be the URL of your server. Also, your submit button should be inside the form element as well !
Hope this helps.